# Uploading Lucene index into Kibana/ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a lucene index built already and wanted to play around with it. There is a GUI tool called Luke, but I thought using Kibana for index exploration could be a more convenient option. Since ElasticSearch uses lucene underneath, I thought it might be possible to load my index into it, but I didn't find a way to do so.

I guess it's not currently possible, but maybe there is a way?

Thanks!